# To resolve a merge conflict, how do I see what change the other branch was making?

Tags: git

I pulled the latest code from the repository with `git pull --rebase`.  My local commit conflicts with one of the remote commits.  The file in question has the merge markers in it, so I can compare my version to their version, but what I really want to know is what change was the other version trying to make?  I want to diff the other change to our common ancestor.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit: gah, I had a broken diagram and description, let's fix it:)

This command will show *everything* that they changed, and you might want to isolate the changes to a specific commit or set of commits and/or files within those commits, but consider doing:

```
$ git diff $(git merge-base master origin/master) origin/master
```

(assuming you're on branch `master`).  This tells git to compare the common ancestor commit to "their" head commit.

Here's a rough sketch of what's going on.  Suppose you started with commits `A`, `B`, and `C` obtained from `origin` (the repo you cloned).  You made commits `D` and `E` and they made `F` and `G`.  You're now in the middle of a conflicted rebase.  (I've assumed here the change in `D` was rebased successfully, giving commit `D'`, and the problem is at `E`.)  The `+i,w` means there is stuff in the index and/or working directory that is not yet committed—that's the commit with conflicts, that you need to resolve.

```
            D - E              <-- master
          /
A - B - C           D' +i,w    <-- HEAD (detached)
          \       /
            F - G              <-- origin/master
```

In this case, `git merge-base master origin/master` finds commit `C`, the common point for the rebase.

Meanwhile `origin/master` names commit `G`.  So:

```
git diff <name-of-commit-C> origin/master
```

shows you everything they did, in both commits `F` and `G` (compares contents of `G` to contents of `C`).  Of course, you can also use `git log` to find the individual commits, or name them with names like `origin/master~1`.  You can also do `git show origin/master` to look at their most recent change `G`, and `git show origin/master~1` to show their change `F`.

Eventually, if once you resolve conflicts and `git rebase --continue` and it reaches the end, git will move the branch label (`master`) to where `HEAD` points, and set `HEAD` to refer back to `master`, rather than being "detached".  Or, if you use `git rebase --abort` it will abandon the new chain and just restore your old `master` (which you can then re-`rebase` later).

(Incidentally, this is one case where graphical tools like `gitk` come in handy.  Bring up `gitk --all` or `gitk HEAD master origin/master` on a conflicted rebase and it's often really easy to see where the conflicting commit is.)

For really tough merge cases, there's [git-imerge](http://softwareswirl.blogspot.com/2013/05/git-imerge-practical-introduction.html), which I have not used (yet) but looks really nice.

Answer (score 2):

You have done a pull --rebase, so you already have 'their' commits on your local branch (HEAD). You might have applied some of your commits until the conflict arrised. Therefore you can check all the changes by commits:

```
git log -p file
```

You can further narrow it down by adding revision range from common ancestor:

```
git log -p common..HEAD file
```

When the pull --rebase already applied 2 of your commits before the conflict arrised (you see them as last commits in the log) and wish to see just 'their' changes against the common ancestor:

```
git log -p common..HEAD^^ file
```

Comment: How do I know that the common ancestor is?  Maybe I should have copied it before I ran the pull.

Comment: You can check that with git merge-base bra origin/bra, where bra is the name of your branch.

Answer (score 1):

Before rebasing, run:

```
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

as documented in [the git-config man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html). This causes git to include the most recent common ancestor's text along with each conflicting change.

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly how I wished conflicts were recorded.  That will definitely help me in the future.  Thanks so much!